# how to convert array chunk in twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I want to convert the following line from PHP to twig I tried many methods but no use can anyone guide me how to do...

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($images, 4) as $image) { ?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($image['type'] == 'image') { ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_chunk` is built-in `twig` as the [`slice`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html)-filter

```
{% for image in images|slice(0,4) %}
    {% if image.type == 'image' %}
        {# I am an image #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can shorten above example by moving the `if` inside the `for-loop`

```
{% for image in images|slice(0,4) %}
    {% if image.type == 'image' %}
        {# I am an image #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

[documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html)

Comment: I am new to twig so can you describe this in detail

Comment: Which part? I've added a link to the slice documentation in the answer

Answer (score 15):

### Use Twig's built in batch() filter

The **[batch filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)** splits the original array into a number of chunks.
Check out this example for better clarification:

```
{% set items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] %}

<table>
{#The first param to batch() is the size of the batch#}
{#The 2nd param is the text to display for missing items#}
{% for row in items|batch(3, 'No item') %}
    <tr>
        {% for column in row %}
            <td>{{ column }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This would be rendered as:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>No item</td>
        <td>No item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/batch.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add an else clause using the empty block in Twig. Here's how to do it:

```
{% for image in images|slice(0, 4) if image.type == 'image' %}
   {# I am an image #}
{% else %}
  {# No images found #}
{% endfor %}
```

In this example, if there are no images that match the condition (image.type == 'image'), the block inside the else will be executed indicating "No images found".

Comment: Using an if inside the for is now deprecated